# Make substitute in all Wordpress posts

Tags: post-editor

I wish to replace one string in all my WP posts (over one hundred).

There is a "bulk edit" feature, but I do not think it covers this feature.

I can think of downloading the database, open it with an editor and make a replace. In a GUI editor this may fail since the file is so large. If I read up on database structure and MySQL I can probably isolate the variable containing the post texts and only edit that one. It is probably best to use a line editor like SED.

At present I don't use MySQL and SED daily and it will take some time to experiment with and also verify that file is OK.

Is there any quick way to make an edit-replace command over all my WP posts?

(The reason I need to do this is that the latest update of "Insert PHP" plug-in does not allow PHP written straight into the pages, which I have used.)

Comment: Globally replacing a simple string in multiple posts is quite simple, I am just not certain this is exactly what you need. Can you give an example of the string, and confirm it is simply added in the editing screen of a bunch of posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this here a couple:

1) You can use something like:

Better search and replace plugin here: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

or

SAFE SEARCH AND REPLACE ON DATABASE WITH SERIALIZED DATA script here: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Both of these with serialize the data, which is important for many themes and plugins.

There is a good explanation of WP Serialized data here:
 https://wpengine.com/support/wordpress-serialized-data/

Comment: Thank you. This will run in web browser which is good for me (I do not have SSH on this server). I am not familiar with the term "serialization", is it something that may affect the result of the action? (I tried to Google it but for safety I ask.)

Comment: Since I am not sure of the consequences of serialization, I should probably use The Search and Replace plugin which "offers an *option* which handles serialized data" so I can opt out of serialized data?

Comment: Can you please verify the statement in your answer "Both of these with serialize the data". Is this correct or are the editors only *capable* of handling serialized data? They will not *introduce* serialized data? Sorry I am very new to serialization, can someone please verify this?

Comment: Yes these both do the same thing. Neither will inject serialization, they just both handle it so if a value is serialized it will keep the sterilization and not invalidate the row.

Answer (score 1):

You mention Sed so you may be familiar or comfortable with command line usage. If so, I'd recommend WP-CLI. We use this constantly via SSH to do just that.

After [WP-CLI is installed](https://wp-cli.org/#installing), you will want to run the [wp-cli search-replace command](https://github.com/wp-cli/search-replace-command). Example usage:

`wp-cli search-replace 'old string' 'new-string' --dry-run`

Keep `--dry-run` in place to make sure it's doing what you want it to do. Nothing will be affected in the database.  When you're ready to make a permanent change to the database, remove it.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a really good idea. I wait a little and see if more suggestions come in before I approve the answer. I dont have SSH on this server (GoDaddy web hosting), can it run over normal WP http interface?